# IOptions<AppSettings> with Base implementation

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

In my .Net Project I have two projects.

The Infrastrucure project contains a AppSettings.cs with the following structure:

```
public class AppSettings 
{
    public string TenantId { get; set; }
}
```

And an appsettings.json file with the following structure:

```
{
    "TenantId": "131283"
}
```

Then I have an WebApi project, that should have its own additional settings, which are defined by the following AppSettings.cs:

```
public class AppSettings: Infrastructure.AppSettings 
{
    public string DbConnection { get; set; }
}
```

And an own appsettings.json with the following structure:

```
{
    "DbConnection": "sdamlkdsakldsalk"
}
```

In the Infrastructure project I defined my own ProgramBase.cs in the following way:

```
public static class ProgramBase
{
    public static WebApplicationBuilder Build(WebApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.Configure<AppSettings>(builder.Configuration);
        builder.Services.AddScoped(s => s.GetRequiredService<IOptions<AppSettings>>().Value);
    }
}
```

The Program.cs of my WebApi project looks like this:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    builder.Services.Configure<AppSettings>(builder.Configuration);
    builder.Services.AddScoped(s => s.GetRequiredService<IOptions<AppSettings>>().Value.DbConfiguration);

    // Call to Infrastructure Program class.
    builder = ProgramBase.Build(builder);
}
```

When I try to inject the IOption<Infrastructure.AppSettings> into any other class, the TenantId is always empty. Am I missing anything?

Comment: IMHO `services.AddScoped<IOptions<Infrastructure.AppSettings>>(s => s.GetRequiredService<IOptions<AppSettings>())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your executable project, in this case the Web API project has no knowledge of a separate appsettings.json, it will only load the appsettings.json file in it's own project folder which is copied .

If you think about how you will deploy your app, it may make more sense. Let's say you will host it on Azure App Service for example, you will not have multiple project folders with multiple executable and appsettings.json files. You will have one folder with all the required binaries and a single appsettings.json (and maybe additional environment specific appsettings.{Environment}.json files, but still in the same folder).

When you run locally something similar happens, your compiled project is running from a similar build folder, you can verify that the [WebAPI]/bin/Debug... folder will only contain the appsettings.json from your Web API project.

**TL;DR** just update your WebAPI's appsettings.json file to include both settings:

```
{
    "TenantId": "131283",
    "DbConnection": "sdamlkdsakldsalk"
}
```

You can still keep the code separate, although I don't know why a DbConnection would not be an Infrastructure concern, but I will stay out of that as you may have a good reason. Also you may want to consider using different names for your classes to make it easier on other people reading your code.

Comment: But what if, lets say I have 5 WebApi Projects that all share the Infrastructure project and the same TenantId?
I dont want to specify the TenantId in all single appsettings of my WebApi projects.

Comment: To be able to do that see Qing's answer. But I will suggest you set optional: true when calling AddJsonFile, because it is likely that this will eventually get deployed outside your local environment and probably won't share the same folder structure as your code solution. Also this link may be helpful: https://andrewlock.net/sharing-appsettings-json-configuration-files-between-projects-in-asp-net-core/.

Answer (score 0):

> the TenantId is always empty.

Try to register  Infrastructure project json file into api project Program.cs like below, we can register it using a host configurator extension named  ConfigureAppConfiguration. Inside its closure, we just need to call `AddJsonFile()`:

```
builder.Host.ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
{
    config.AddJsonFile("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\source\\repos\\DropdownR\\DropdownR\\appsettings.json");
});//add your json file path
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problems comes from the fact that the `appsettings.json` inside the Infrastructure service is not read.

When you run the WebApi project only the `appsettings.json` (`appsettings.development.json` and so on) inside the `WebApi` project is read.

Saying so, you have to enrich your ConfigurationBuilder to tell it to read the `appsettings.json` file inside the infrastructure project. (using `builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile()`)

Answer (score 0):

**TenantSettings.cs**

```
public class TenantSettings 
{
     public string TenantId { get; set; }
}
```

**appsettings.Development.json**

```
{
    "TenantSettings": {
        "TenantId": "131283"
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.Configure<TenantSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("TenantSettings"));
```